# Any pro components out there that record screen, mouse and keyboard?

Tags: components, desktop-application, video-recording, desktop-recording

I'm looking for professional software components capable of recording the screen (primarily), mouse movement/clicks and key strokes.

I need to embed such a component in a LOB app to empower users with a one-click ability to record their interaction with this app when they encounter an issue they can't easily explain in other ways.

Major technical requirements:

- Usable on Windows in a .NET app
- Pro-level code & product quality
- Capable of efficient recordings with various codecs

I found very few options out there and they don't scream pro to me. Here they are:

- [BB FlashBack SDK](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/BBFlashBackSDK/FeaturesPricing.aspx)
- [Bytescout Screen Capturing SDK](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/screencapturingsdk/screencapturingsdk.html)

Anyone knows better alternatives or has experiences with these 2 options?

Answer (score 0):

While ByteScout and others are good, there are some good alternatives tools for the screen recording worth to mention:

- [MediaLooks screen recording filter (commercial)](http://www.medialooks.com/screen_capture/)
- [DirectShow recording filter based recorder](https://github.com/rdp/screen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free)
- [Ffmpeg/VLC based recorder](https://github.com/Slasict/recordify-screen-recorder)

*Disclosure: I am affiliated with ByteScout*